# Clearing all logs

Tags: command-line

I would like to delete all logs, temp files, bash history, anything that will have left a trail of user activity whilst building my virtual machine image. The reason for this is that I want to have a clean image for cloning and I don't want the old user activity being cloned on to other virtual machines.

Is there a general bash script that will clear the basic logs? What actually made me think this existed is that I had a honeypot that collected commands and I came across a bot that issued a salvo of commands that appeared to try to erase a whole suite of logs in an effort cover it's tracks. This made me think there must be a collection of commands that cover most common logs including ones I didn't know about.

or is it just /var/log/* and 'history' I should be concerned about?